# Play a new video upon refresh

Tags: javascript, html, video

i'm trying to make a video player that plays a new video every time I refresh the page. How would this be accomplished and what language would I use? 
Example:So say I have a website with 3 videos on it, Once you load the webpage, a video starts playing. If you reload the page another random video starts playing (Only 1 video per refresh). Once you refresh the page again, another video starts playing and so on. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: You can use any programming language.

Comment: if you have some code, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a video via html

```
<video id="videoItem">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

than using javascript, you can change the source url of the video.
store different video urls in a array, and use a random int to choose one of the urls

```
<script>
    // function to generate random int inside a given range
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    var video = document.getElementById('videoItem');
    var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
    var videoUrlsMp4=["URL1.mp4", "URL2.mp4", "URL3.mp4"];
    var videoUrlsOgg4=["URL1.ogg", "URL2.ogg", "URL3.ogg"];
    var random_nr = getRandomInt(0, videoUrlsMp4.length-1);
    sources[0].src = videoUrlsMp4[random_nr ];
    sources[1].src = videoUrlsOgg4[random_nr ];
    video.load();
</script>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Let me try this and i'll get tell you if it works :)